Were you diagnose with adhd?can you hear your internal monologue?
Trying to see how many people that were diagnosed with adhd that can hear their internal monologue or can't hear their internal monologue.

I’m voting to close this question because poll questions are off-topic on Stack Exchange.

If you re-write it as an on-topic question then add your researches into the answer, it may be better received.
